# id of above class using jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the id of the div above a tag and of click tag.

html code:

```
<div id='myId`' class="abc"> 
  <a>
    <div class="clickonNext"></div>
  </a>
</div>
```

js code:

```
$('.clickonNext_v1').bind( "click", function() {
    // here i i want to get id of abc i.e of div->a->link clicked  ==> i need myId
    callMe();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest("div.abc").attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.clickonNext_v1').bind( "click", function() {

  id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');

    // here i i want to get id of abc i.e of div->a->link clicked  ==> i need myId
    callMe();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.clickonNext').on('click',function(){
var parentId = $(this).closest('div')[0].id;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parents()` as well:-

```
$('.clickonNext').on('click',function(){
$(this).parents("div").attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use "parent()" method.

```
$('.clickonNext_v1').bind( "click", function() {

    // use directly
    //alert($(this).parent().parent().attr("id"));

    // store a variable
    var obj = $(this).parent().parent();
    alert(obj.attr("id"));
});
```